# Easiest way to retrieve latest tweet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I have been poking around with the Twitter framework for a bit and I'm wondering, is there an easy way to retrieve the lastest tweet from a user instead of a ton at once?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use either `TWRequest` or `SLRequest` (iOS 6+). First you have to get your twitter account with `ACAccount`. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/3866796) a example.

And then, you have to perform a request to the twitter API to get the last tweets. You can set the cardinality, as many other things trough the different params you will find [her](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline).

The request can be performed either with TWRequest (deprecated in iOS 6) or with `SLRequest` (introduced in iOS 6). [Here](https://gist.github.com/3866791) an example of how to determine which one to use.

You have to remember to link the frameworks.